# Как запретить изменение размера окна в winforms c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как оставить только один размер окна и запретить его изменение winforms c#???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
```

если не нужны кнопки свернуть и развернуть то

```
form.MaximizeBox = false;
form.MinimizeBox = false;
```

Comment: или же выставить все эти значения через инспектор